# Access Query for Ranking/Assigning Priority Values

Tags: sql, ms-access, ranking

I am doing data conversion from a previous system that was keyed in without validation rules. I am working with a table of Emergency Contacts, and trying to assign a primary contact with (`Y`/`N`) when the field is blank or duplicated (i.e. someone puts `Y` or `N` for multiple contacts I want to arbitrarily assign primary). I will also assign a new column with an alphabetic sequence (`a`, `b`, `c`, etc.) based on the priority which was designated in the other column.

Every ID must only have 1 Priority 'Y'.

Current Table:

```
+--------+---------+----------+
|   id   |  fname  | pri_cont |
+--------+---------+----------+
| 001000 | Rox     | Y        |
| 001000 | Dan     | N        |
| 001002 | May     | Y        |
| 001007 | Lee     | Y        |
| 001007 | Clive   | Y        |
| 001008 | Max     | Y        |
| 001008 | Kim     | N        |
| 001013 | Sam     | Y        |
| 001013 | Ann     |          |
| 001014 | Nat     | Y        |
| 001018 | Bruce   | Y        |
| 001018 | Mel     |          |
| 001020 | Wilson  | Y        |
| 001022 | Goi     | Y        |
| 001022 | Adele   | N        |
| 001022 | Gary    | N        |
+--------+---------+----------+
```

What I want:

```
+--------+---------+----------+----------+
|   id   |  fname  | pri_cont | priority |
+--------+---------+----------+----------+
| 001000 | Rox     | Y        | a        |
| 001000 | Dan     | N        | b        |
| 001002 | May     | Y        | a        |
| 001007 | Lee     | Y        | a        |
| 001007 | Clive   | N        | b        |
| 001008 | Max     | Y        | a        |
| 001008 | Kim     | N        | b        |
| 001013 | Sam     | Y        | a        |
| 001013 | Ann     | N        | b        |
| 001014 | Nat     | Y        | a        |
| 001018 | Bruce   | Y        | a        |
| 001018 | Mel     | N        | b        |
| 001020 | Wilson  | Y        | a        |
| 001022 | Goi     | Y        | a        |
| 001022 | Adele   | N        | b        |
| 001022 | Gary    | N        | c        |
+--------+---------+----------+----------+
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I see it your cleanup requires several queries (please note queries assume Emergency Contacts table has a unique autonumber, dbID):

One Select Query to count Y and N instances. Also, query can calculate Priority column using the [Chr ASCII conversion](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/chr.php) of numbers to letters.:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.fname, t1.pri_cont, 

     (SELECT Count(*) 
      FROM EmergContacts t2 
      WHERE t1.dbID >= t2.dbID AND t1.ID = t2.ID 
        AND t1.pri_cont = t2.pri_cont AND t1.pri_cont = 'Y') AS YCount, 

     (SELECT Count(*) 
      FROM EmergContacts t3 
      WHERE t1.dbID >= t3.dbID AND t1.ID = t3.ID 
        AND t1.pri_cont = t3.pri_cont AND t1.pri_cont = 'N') AS NCount,

     (SELECT Chr(Count(t2.ID) + 96) 
      FROM EmergContacts t2 
      WHERE t1.dbID >= t2.dbID AND t1.ID = t2.ID) AS Priority

FROM EmergContacts AS t1;
```

With output such as below:

```
ID   |  fname    |  pri_cont |  YCount | NCount | Priority
1000 |  Rox      |  Y        |  1      | 0      | a
1000 |  Dan      |  N        |  0      | 1      | b
1002 |  May      |  Y        |  1      | 0      | a
1007 |  Lee      |  Y        |  1      | 0      | a
1007 |  Clive    |  Y        |  2      | 1      | b
1008 |  Max      |  Y        |  1      | 0      | a
1008 |  Kim      |  N        |  0      | 1      | b
1013 |  Sam      |  Y        |  1      | 0      | a
1013 |  Ann      |           |  0      | 1      | b
1014 |  Nat      |  Y        |  1      | 0      | a
1018 |  Bruce    |  Y        |  1      | 0      | a
1018 |  Mel      |           |  0      | 1      | b
1020 |  Wilson   |  Y        |  1      | 0      | a
1022 |  Goi      |  Y        |  1      | 0      | a
1022 |  Adele    |  N        |  0      | 1      | b
1022 |  Gary     |  N        |  0      | 2      | c
```

From there you run three update queries:

To clean up Nulls:

```
UPDATE EmergContacts 
SET pri_cont = 'N'
WHERE pri_cont Is Null;
```

To clean up IDs with more than 1 Ys:

```
UPDATE EmergContacts 
SET pri_cont = 'N'
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM EmergContPrCount WHERE YCount > 1)
  AND fName IN (SELECT fName FROM EmergContPrCount WHERE YCount > 1);
```

And to clean up IDs with no Ys:

```
UPDATE EmergContacts 
SET pri_cont = 'Y'
WHERE (ID IN (SELECT ID FROM EmergContPrCount WHERE YCount = 0)
  AND fName IN (SELECT Max(fName) FROM EmergContPrCount WHERE YCount = 0));
```

Comment: Thanks!  Appreciate you taking the time to answer.